# How can I tell Google not to crawl a set of Urls

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

How do I stop google to crawl to certain urls in my application?

For example: I want google to stop crawling all the URLs that starts with `http://www.myhost-test.com/`

What should I add in my robot.txt?

Comment: Did you try searching at all?

Comment: people who took down this question please specify reason ?

Answer (score 2):

The answer can be found directly here:

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449

But it looks like you add "disallow" and your url.